# How can create multiple filters using Uikit?

Tags: filter, uikit

please, how can I create a filter with Uikit that filters multiple items at the same time, without excluding the other.

I mean, I'm creating a list of games and I need that when someone selects PS4 and then ADVENTURE, I want the PS4 filter to continue while now only the PS4 adventure games appears.

```
<div class="uk-grid-small uk-grid-divider uk-child-width-auto" uk-grid>
    <div>
        <ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill" uk-margin>
            <li class="uk-active" uk-filter-control><a href="#">All</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="uk-subnav uk-subnav-pill" uk-margin>
            <li uk-filter-control="[data-game='adventure']"><a href="#">White</a></li>
            <li uk-filter-control="[data-console='ps4']"><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>


    </div>
</div>

<ul class="js-filter uk-child-width-1-2 uk-child-width-1-3@m uk-text-center" uk-grid="masonry: true">
    <li data-color="white" data-size="large">
        <div data-game="xbox" >
            <canvas width="600" height="800"></canvas>
            <div class="uk-position-center">Item</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-game="adventure">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-primary uk-card-body">
            <canvas width="600" height="400"></canvas>
            <div class="uk-position-center">Item</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-game="adventure" data-console="ps4">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
            <canvas width="600" height="600"></canvas>
            <div class="uk-position-center">Item</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

simply use groups, like this

```
<li uk-filter-control="filter: .thing;group: 1" id="tagy" class=""><a href="#">thing</a></li>
```

if you are using php for this you can do some foreach loop

```
$num = 1;
        foreach(array_unique($alltags) as $key => $tag) {
            echo"<li uk-filter-control='filter: .$tag;group: $num'><a href='#'>$tag</a></li>";
            $num++;
        }
```

this works really well, you can select multiple tags, but dont forget to add clearing button i have it like this

```
        <li class='uk-active' uk-filter-control><a href='#'>Reset</a></li>";
```